# iphone: how to know the application open from background

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, background

I have one problem when developing iphone application. I would like to know if the application reopen from background, how can I realize that state?

That means: I open my application, do some business logic. And after that, I press 'Home' button to give the current application to background state. After that, I double press 'Home' button to see applications run in background. And I select my application to reopen it again. How can I know an application reopen from background state?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register for the [UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) using NSNotificationCenter.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Called as part of  transition from the background to the active state: here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
     */
}
```

Comment: That method is in ApplicationDelegate. I would like to know it in my current view.

Comment: This delegate will call whenever you enter from background, no matters about the views.

Comment: Why should you want to find out the view?

Comment: Because if you cram everything into the app delegate methods you gather a lot of view/object dependent stuff into a place where it doesn't belong to. The app delegate would need to know about all those objects which is not a good design. Better to subscribe to the notification and handle stuff local in your object. Way better and more flexible encapsulation.

Comment: @DarkDust yes, you are right. The app delegate should not handle the view in this method. Thank you.